# Python duvida sintaxe

Tags: python

Galera estava estudando python e vi em um site esta linha :

```
self.brotcl.plugins.runCustumcomand()
```

Sei que self esta referenciando uma classe mas e essas três variáveis juntas como assim ?

Answer (score 4):

`self` está referenciando o próprio objeto que possui um atributo chamado `brotctl`.

`self.brotctl` é um objeto que possui o atributo `plugins`.

Da mesma forma, `self.brotctl.plugins` é um objeto que possui o método `runCustomcomand`.

Um exemplo de implementação para o que você apresenta, seria:

```
class Plugins:

    def runCustomcomand(self):
        pass    


class Brotctl:

    def __init__(self):
        self.plugins = Plugins()


class Exemplo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.broatctl = Broatctl()

    def run(self):
        self.broatctl.plugins.runCustomcomand()
```